# Convert existing Wordpress Site (with several plugins) into Multisite

Tags: plugins, multisite

I want to convert an existing Wordpress Site into a Multisite. I have several
plugins installed. Is there a special preperation needed to get this plugins safely into the multisite mode?

Do I have to follow a special workflow.

Comment: As far as I know it won't break anything but it is hard to say how each plugin will react on MU.

Answer (score 1):

You can always read through the documentation that WordPress.org has put together on [Creating A Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network).

The point below was taken from Step 1:

> "Also deactivate all active plugins. You can reactivate them again
>   after the network is created."

After the network is created I recommend activating your Plugins one by one and testing your site each time you have activated one

**Site note:** Also make sure you **backup** your database before you even start doing anything with MultiSite

Best of luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously there are steps. And you have to choose whether you want to go with subdomain or subfolder (and under certain condition [you can overwrite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration#Switching_network_types) your own choice upon the default).

I found a nice step-by-step guide to WordPress Multisite Helpful is:

- **[The Complete Guide To Creating A WordPress Multisite Installation](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/the-complete-guide-to-creating-a-wordpress-multisite-installation)** by *Kevin Muldoon*

It has a good tail with Fallback too - that tells how to fallback to a single site from a Multisite, that's nice. :) (BTW, don't rely on that, take backup of everything(file+database) before proceeding to multisite)

---

BTW, WordPress Multisite is a different concept. But everything will go nice by default if the thing is made WordPress-specific. If the thing is done by other means, without knowing how WordPress handles sites on Multisite, thing can go wrong.

So, for plugins, you have to know which one works on multisite, which one not. You can find the information on their plugin pages, or support forums. If you can't find, ask them about it. In my case I's using [Redirection plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) and on switching to multisite, I found it won't work on multisite. So I made [my own for temporary purposes](https://github.com/nanodesigns/nano-redirection). But it's buggy <sup>(I'm warning you :) )</sup>.

Mutisite is a different experience. You can obviously make a try on development environment at least. :)